# using WebGL through emscripten on an html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, c++, html, webgl, emscripten

I have an HTML page with a canvas I've already created and I want to draw on it using WebGL though emscripten. I want the compiled C++ code to make GL calls which will go to that canvas I created in the HTML.
All examples I've seen use SDL or OpenKODE to create the canvas. I haven't found any that take the canvas from outside.
What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: Which examples have you seen that create the canvas?

Comment: http://blog.scottlogic.com/2014/03/12/native-code-emscripten-webgl-simmer-gently.html  and https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/master/tests/glbook/Chapter_15/Hello_Triangle_KD/Hello_Triangle_KD.c

Answer (score 1):

You can set the canvas element of the module object,

```
var Module = {
  canvas: myCanvasDomElement
};
```